# Java Long Compare and ValueOf method undefined

Tags: java, long-integer, comparator

I am referencing my java version JDK 1.8 but I am still getting error. What is wrong with this referencing (writing Java after 6 years)? or any other simpler way to do this? I did some search and these functions are available in later java versions. Eclipse is `Oxygen`

> The method valueOf(Long) is undefined for the type Long
>
> The method compareTo() is undefined for the type Long

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.lang.Long;

public class MyComparator<Long> implements Comparator<Long>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Long long1, Long long2) {    
        //Long.compareTo()
          return Long.valueOf(long1).compareTo(Long.valueOf(long2));
    }
}
```

and JDK points to

**/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home**

[image]

Comment: Why did you write `<LONG>`?

Comment: I just noticed after posting the question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your declaration of `MyComparator` declares a generic type of name `Long`, and that then **shadows** `java.lang.Long`. Your class shouldn't be generic. Also, you don't need `Long.valueOf` since you already have `Long` instance. Change it to remove the generic, like

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Long> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Long long1, Long long2) {
        return long1.compareTo(long2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just noticed after posting the question :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively anytime you need `Comparator<Long>` or any other `class` that implements `Comparable` you can call:

```
Comparator.naturalOrder()
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--